# Issue while exporting data Room database from App Inspection : For security reasons offline mode is disabled

Tags: database, android-studio, android-room, offline-mode, app-inspection

I'm trying to export database file from App Inspection Android studio but it shows error like:

**Issue while exporting data Issue**

> while downloading database (app_db): For security reasons offline mode
> is disabled when the process being inspected does not correspond to
> the project open in studio or when the project has been generated from
> a prebuilt apk.

[image]

Comment: Use Device File Explore in Android studio to get your database file. data->data->your-app-package->databases

Comment: You can then use https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser to view your database

Comment: Sometimes the DB isn't a single file, its divided into 3 files as DB connection hasn't closed. Then as well we cannot download the DB file.

Answer (score 7):

i have oppened device file explorer, and tried again and it export successfuly.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34416259)

Comment: Sorry about that, i meant that when i follow that path i'm able to see the database correctly.

Comment: Helped me. I just opened the file explorer and database export from the "app inspection" began to work.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and resolved it finally by replacing it with the version of [Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 RC 1 August 16, 2022](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive)